Stop const form checking (required text field) on initial load
I have a constant and I simply just want to stop it from checking a required text field that it is targeting only on page load to stop the error message from appearing at first:
const fromSchema = computed(() => {
   return props.required
     ? yup.mixed().required(t('this text field is required', [props.fromDateName]))    
     : yup.mixed().notRequired()
})

My main concern is with the .required(), it checks the textfield it is in when I load the page where this const is being used.
what I tried:

onMount()
onClick()

This is also a date check (calendar date picker)
What should I modify with yup.mixed().required(t('message.error.ECM119', [props.fromDateName])) to stop my issue from happening?
Update:

I cannot use onClick() because I need the error to just display whenever the datepicker is clicked (calendar picker)

Update 2:

just to note that this const is not on any onLoad() or document.Ready

Update 3:
<FieldError :key="errorMessage" :message="errorMessage" />


for conventional purposes on the rest of the code, I have to put the error within a tag, there was a suggestion of using @blur but I do not think I can use it on the code above:


You can use @blur and check the required method on that instead of using a computed property.

im updating again, i dont think i can use @blur either

Can you create a reproducible example link like a codepen or code sandbox?
